# How to JsonPost to a WebService target in Nlog

Tags: json, web-services, nlog, slack

With Nlog 4.4.5 am trying to use protocol JsonPost of WebService target to post logs to slack. Slack webhooks need Json data over https post (https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks)

```xml
<target xsi:type="WebService"
            name="slack"
            url="https://hooks.slack.com/services/T*****/B4T****/7F********XDv9h/"
            protocol="JsonPost"
            encoding="utf-8"
            >

    <parameter name="text" type="System.String" layout="${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss.fff}: ${level} - ${message}"/> 

</target>
```

It does not post anything to my slack channel created for the webhook whereas I see the other targets in my Nlog.config are called and log files are populated with new data.

Any idea where I should look into to sort it out?

Comment: Check the internal log for errors: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-logging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with the ending "/" in the Slack webhook url. Removed and it started posting logs to my slack channel.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this answer:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1958

While waiting for this issue to be resolved (Using JSON-Layout directly):

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1905

Comment: I think I just need to make sure the json data generated by the layout is in the correct format. Wish I could get it logged into NLog's Internal Logs?